# SQL Server Union with SELECT TOP(x) optimisation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, optimization, union

I recently handled a call where a query that is run (via entity framework) was timing out. This was from code written by another developer that did the following.

A complex set of 2 `IQueryable`s were created and then joined together with a `Union`:

```
IQueryable<AwardListing> listData = null;
listData = GetGoodsAwards();
listData = listData.Union(GetServicesAwards());
```

Next an set of filters were applied to the resulting `IQueryable` based on input from the user and applied to different columns:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReferenceNumberOrKeyword))
{
    Expression<Func<AwardListing, bool>> referenceOrKeywordFilter = r => r.ReferenceNumber.ToLower().Contains(ReferenceNumberOrKeyword.ToLower())
                                                                                || r.Title.ToLower().Contains(ReferenceNumberOrKeyword.ToLower());
    listData = listData.Where(referenceOrKeywordFilter);
}

// more filters applied etc.
```

Finally, the top 100 records were returned, since the full set would often contain too many records to pass to the client:

```
 return listData.Take(100).ToList<AwardListing>();
```

I ran the query in SQL server to investigate the execution plan:

[image]

An odd thing I discovered was that the query was much faster when not selecting the top 100 records (as shown above). The execution plan of the right-side query revealed that the delay was caused by the union:

[image]

I found this odd, as both queries had the union. The only difference is the `TOP(100)`, however I took steps to repair the issue by removing the union from the equation. I did this by keeping the 2 `IQueryable`s apart, applying the filters to both, then executing them and joining them together in-memory. This greatly reduced the overall execution time of the search for the end-user.

Now, I have to fill out non-conformity paperwork as a requirement from the organization. I don't quite know what to say in the:

> Action to prevent Non-conformity in future

section, since I'm not completely sure what the root cause of the issue is. I'm hesitant to say: do not make use of SQL Union's, since this on it's own does not seem to be the cause of my problem.

Comment: Unions are great; Although Linq's usage might often be.... funny. But maybe this can help you shed some light on things: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---concatenation

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan